# Expected xml tag got no content in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing

I am using this function:

```
FUNCTION XMLTEST (P_XML VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
V_FLAG VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
WITH test_data AS
  (SELECT xmltype('<boolean xmlns="http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods">false</boolean>') data
FROM dual)

SELECT extractValue(data,'/boolean','xmlns="http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods"')
FROM test_data;

return V_FLAG;
```

This method is working and it it returns the exact boolean value that I want which is false in our example. But when I use P_XML parameter instead of the hard-coded value, an error is displayed: "expected xml tag, got no content" while the passed P_XML is the same xml structure that I copied from the example above:
 `<boolean xmlns="http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods">false</boolean>`. How can I resolve this problem?

Code that is not working:

```
FUNCTION XMLTEST (P_XML VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    V_FLAG VARCHAR2(4000);

    BEGIN
    WITH test_data AS
      (SELECT xmltype(P_XML) data
                  FROM dual
      )

    SELECT extractValue(data,'/boolean','xmlns="http://SOAPwebservice.com/WebServices/Methods"')
    FROM test_data;

    return V_FLAG;
```

[image: This is my error:]

Comment: Show us the entire code that is not working. Including function call.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Please check the updates, thank you

Comment: You forgot the function call. Apparently in your call, `P_XML` is empty.

Comment: OMG! I was confusing between p_xml and result in oracle test,thank you very much for your clarification